# Google App Engine - Python - Flask - oauth2client - "Invalid request state" error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-oauth

I'm trying to write a simple Google App Engine app that pulls my Google Calendar events. Here's my code:

```
import os

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.contrib.flask_util import UserOAuth2
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'secret'

app.config['GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID'] = 'xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com'
app.config['GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET'] = 'secret'

oauth2 = UserOAuth2(app)

@app.route('/')
@oauth2.required(scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'])
def home():
    http = oauth2.http()
    service = build('calendar', 'v3', http=http)
    result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary').execute()
    return "Hello, {} ({})".format(oauth2.email, oauth2.user_id)
```

After authenticating, I see `"Invalid request state"` in the browser. The URL is:

```
http://localhost:8080/oauth2callback?state=%7B%22csrf_token%22:+%22863627a865be2113450700ee52763f37522e62b5c97e942375ec5377ab0dc390%22,+%22return_url%22:+%22http://localhost:8080/%22%7D&code=4/AADbqpPPhHQlv_lYPOCe9Q8DsO6XHzD-uJXKQfd9yYO7dMSQAj7rcdLdBED2LqQsJ7x0eBZTgPLFPtLpPC5o7lw#
```

Logs:

```
2604:2000:8147:1b00:7d6f:b191:cd7a:321a - - [17/Jul/2018:16:41:03 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 540 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36" "xxx.appspot.com" ms=NaN cpu_ms=3121 cpm_usd=6.034899999999999e-8 loading_request=1 instance=00c61b117cdb6fb6db16f355621aff162c3bd9b98966a1d2514536dd6fba1692ec1430e596 app_engine_release=1.9.54 trace_id=f6f416d28263cd8f184f8f17707dbce8
2604:2000:8147:1b00:7d6f:b191:cd7a:321a - - [17/Jul/2018:16:41:05 -0400] "GET /oauth2authorize?scopes=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcalendar.readonly&scopes=email&return_url=https%3A%2F%2Fxxx.appspot.com%2F HTTP/1.1" 302 5280 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36" "xxx.appspot.com" ms=NaN cpu_ms=28 cpm_usd=5.90085e-7 loading_request=0 instance=00c61b117cdb6fb6db16f355621aff162c3bd9b98966a1d2514536dd6fba1692ec1430e596 app_engine_release=1.9.54 trace_id=2ecc3838c2381b5ca92d3301eea94675
2604:2000:8147:1b00:7d6f:b191:cd7a:321a - - [17/Jul/2018:16:41:09 -0400] "GET /oauth2callback?state=%7B%22csrf_token%22:+%22a827600a31bdb8e006d7bc2eab173ef2f7956e4828ba36ff5c06c298e73ff89b%22,+%22return_url%22:+%22https://xxx.appspot.com/%22%7D&code=4/AACb5iinwvIm2Suc5gYw-LHAqD3yYHS9TUfhubnEFJ70tRPSu24eWWepc2eetThc0g2_S1H7OvMVNVLr_zHoRPE HTTP/1.1" 400 101 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36" "xxx.appspot.com" ms=NaN cpu_ms=7 cpm_usd=1.1287e-8 loading_request=0 instance=00c61b117cdb6fb6db16f355621aff162c3bd9b98966a1d2514536dd6fba1692ec1430e596 app_engine_release=1.9.54 trace_id=6a1e42f8ea14328e8a575eb109021550
```

Some research ([Invalid request state: oauth2 flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36526212/invalid-request-state-oauth2-flask)) shows that cookie size may be the issue?

[image: Cookie size]

How do I store session information in a different way? Thanks!

Comment: A good practice is to avoid posting sensitive personal information, like in your case - the client_id. Try to sanitize the code and logs before posting them on SO. Regarding your question, I am slightly confused as to what the issue is. 
Are you following some documentation for this project? What do the logs in Stackdriver show when you attempt to authenticate and see the error in the browser? Please keep in mind to sanitise the log information.

Comment: Thanks for sanitizing @PhilippSh. I added logs above. Today it's working locally but I'm getting the same "Invalid request state" after deploying. http://oauth2client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/oauth2client.contrib.flask_util.html mentions "you will need to implement your own oauth2client.Storage" but I'm a little lost by https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth#storage and https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/google_app_engine. Thanks!

Comment: I've been trying your code, it looks cool to me, I liked it.

Comment: @trhaynes Did you ever resolve this issue? I am facing the same problem